# Function interpreter in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, probability, interpreter

Suppose I have a function in Python that includes mathematical expressions from Python's base and some mathematical expressions from Numpy and Scipy, including maybe some distributions. As a running example, consider:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import *

def my_process(args):
  """ My process
  """
  x1 = norm.rvs(loc=0, scale=1)
  x2 = x1 + norm.rvs(loc=2, scale=0.5)
  x3 = (x1 * np.exp(x2)) + norm.rvs(loc=-1, scale=2)

  return x1, x2, x3
```

I want to write an interpreter of this function and make each one of the appearing variables into a class, which generically is written as follows:

```
class genericProcess():
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def process(self, parents):
    """ This needs to be implemented for each class
    """
    raise NotImplementedError
```

So for our example function, we would interpret the given function as the following three classes:

```
class x1Process(genericProcess):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def process(self):
    return norm.rvs(loc=0, scale=1)

class x2Process(genericProcess):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def process(self, parents):
    return parents["x1"] + norm.rvs(loc=2, scale=0.5)

class x3Process(genericProcess):
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def process(self, parents):
    return (parents["x1"] * parents["x2"]) + norm.rvs(loc=-1, scale=2)
```

Is this even possible at all? if yes, what would be the first steps to start implementing it, if not, what would make the problem well-posed so that I can start implementing it? For example, I thought having a string instead of a function might make the problem simpler, although I am not sure.

EDIT:

Thanks to the comments I can make the question a bit more concrete. I want a function, called "my_interpreter" that takes as input a user specified function and outputs a dictionary where each key is a line of the function (or alternatively each key is one of the return elements of the function), and each item of the dictionary is a class that implements the "process" method of the "genericProcess" class. I our running example:

```
interpreted_function_dictionary = my_interpreter(my_process)
```

with

```
interpreted_function = {
  "x1": x1Process,
  "x2": x2Process,
  "x3": x3Process
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You're basically describing a DAG (directed acyclic graph) of computation nodes.

Comment: @AKX Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain to me how would I start doing such a thing? Is there a package that allows me to do it? Or maybe I somehow need to be able to read the function lines?

Comment: Oh, if your intention is to make an interpreter for _any arbitrary_ (supported) function, then you'd need e. g. the `ast` module (built-in) for parsing a function into a Python abstract syntax tree, figuring out the variable assignments and reads and building a node tree out of it...

Comment: What's the purpose of the classes here? There doesn't seem to be any use of `self`.

Comment: @AKX yes, what I am thinking about is a function that takes a user defined function and outputs a dictionary with the classes. Something like `my_interpreter(user_function)`. I will edit my question to make this more clear. Thank you for your comments, it helps me make my ideas more concrete.

Comment: @rici This is a very simple case, the base class has more methods and attributes, but I thought that if I can interpret the basic "process" method of the class, I could also probably interpret the other attributes.

Comment: @Sergio Okay, so, next question: why do you want to do this? What's your end goal? (You've tagged `probability`, does that have something to do with this..?)

Comment: @AKX I tagged `probability` as well because I consider the stochastic distributions of scipy important in my task. I am working on a toyish probabilistic programming language (ppl) (as numpyro, pymc, etc), but the heavy lifting of the ppl is done through classes that implement the nodes of the graph. From the user perspective, I want it to implement a DAG as simple as writing the process in a single function as in the `my_process` running example.

Comment: @AKX but beyond the specific task, I do want to learn more about interpreters and compilers. This is the first time I try to tackle such type of task, and as you might have noticed, I am definitely a beginner on the matter and have lots to learn.

Comment: Fair enough. Well, as said, see the AST for your target function(s); there are syntax tree -adjacent libraries such as https://pypi.org/project/libcst/ and https://pypi.org/project/astroid/ that might help.

Comment: @AKX Thank you very much I will start studying then :)

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to intercept definition. You would need to parse the code with `ast` as suggested in the comments.

### `sympy`

An alternative way of doing it is replacing all the math operations into their symbolic representation, which are executable at a later time. The `sympy` package does exactly that and should contain most math operations you need. There is also the `sympy.stats` which has most of the stats functions. (Very similar to symbolic computation in `matlab` with `syms`.)

To use `sympy` with `numpy` backend, you can use their `lambdify` function, e.g.

```
from sympy import sin, lambdify
from sympy.abc import x
expr = sin(x)/x
f = lambdify(x, expr, "numpy")
```

As of version 1.11, it doesn't seem to support `scipy` yet.

### DIY :)

Similar to `sympy`, you can create wrapper classes for all the math operations that would return an expression instead of the result. Then, each expression would be your `process` and you can evaluate each expression to get the resulting value.

Not sure if this fits OP's requirement.

#### for Numpy, Scipy functions

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Any, ClassVar

import numpy as np
import scipy


@dataclass
class EvaluatableExpression:
    name: str
    args: Any = field(default_factory=tuple)
    kwargs: Any = field(default_factory=dict)
    package: ClassVar = None

    def evaluate(self):
        # recursively evaluate any executable args and kwargs
        args = (arg.evaluate() if isinstance(arg, EvaluatableExpression) else arg for arg in self.args)
        kwargs = {k: v.evaluate() if isinstance(v, EvaluatableExpression) else v for k, v in self.kwargs.items()}
        return getattr(self.package, self.name)(*args, **kwargs)


@dataclass
class NumpyFunc(EvaluatableExpression):
    package: ClassVar = np


@dataclass
class ScipyFunc(EvaluatableExpression):
    package: ClassVar = scipy


@dataclass
class ScipyStats(EvaluatableExpression):
    stats_package: str = ''

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.package = getattr(scipy.stats, self.stats_package)
```

#### for simple binary python math ops

For python math, you can handle them using magic methods:

```
@dataclass
class PythonMath(EvaluatableExpression):
    def evaluate(self):
        # the function names are names of magic methods, e.g. '__add__',
        # assuming only binary ops on args[0] and args[1]
        op0 = self.args[0]
        self.package = op0.evaluate() if isinstance(op0, EvaluatableExpression) else op0

        # save args and load args later so it doesn't change args before and after evaluation
        temp_args = self.args
        self.args = self.args[1:]
        result = super().evaluate()
        self.args = temp_args
        return result


@dataclass
class Operand:
    content: Any

    def __add__(self, other):
        return PythonMath(name='__add__', args=(self.content, other))

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return PythonMath(name='__sub__', args=(self.content, other))

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return PythonMath(name='__mul__', args=(self.content, other))

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        return PythonMath(name='__truediv__', args=(self.content, other))

    ...
```

For `Operand` it's not possible to catch `magic methods` with `__getattr__` or `__getattribute__`. You can write custom metaclass to do that to simplify copying and pasting code.

#### usage

```
def process(args):
    """ My process
    """
    x1 = ScipyStats(stats_package='norm', name='rvs', kwargs={'loc': 0, 'scale': 1})
    x2 = Operand(x1) + ScipyStats(stats_package='norm', name='rvs', kwargs={'loc': 2, 'scale': 0.5})
    x3 = Operand(Operand(x1) * NumpyFunc(name='exp', args=(x2,))) + ScipyStats(stats_package='norm', name='rvs',
                                                                               kwargs={'loc': -1, 'scale': 0.5})

    return x1, x2, x3
```

Now, all the returned variables will be "expressions". We can see

```
>>> print(x[0])
ScipyStats(name='rvs', args=(), kwargs={'loc': 0, 'scale': 1}, stats_package='norm')
>>> print(x[1])
PythonMath(name='__add__', args=(ScipyStats(name='rvs', args=(), kwargs={'loc': 0, 'scale': 1}, stats_package='norm'), ScipyStats(name='rvs', args=(), kwargs={'loc': 2, 'scale': 0.5}, stats_package='norm')), kwargs={})
>>> print(x[2])
PythonMath(name='__add__', args=(PythonMath(name='__mul__', args=(ScipyStats(name='rvs', args=(), kwargs={'loc': 0, 'scale': 1}, stats_package='norm'), NumpyFunc(name='exp', args=(PythonMath(name='__add__', args=(ScipyStats(name='rvs', args=(), kwargs={'loc': 0, 'scale': 1}, stats_package='norm'), ScipyStats(name='rvs', args=(), kwargs={'loc': 2, 'scale': 0.5}, stats_package='norm')), kwargs={}),), kwargs={})),
```

And evaluating them gives:

```
>>> print(x[0].evaluate())
-1.331802485169775
>>> print(x[1].evaluate())
0.7789471967940289
>>> print(x[2].evaluate())
-60.03245897617831
```

#### prettify

Of course, you can make defining math expression prettier and more concise by defining aliases, e.g. borrowing from `pyspark` library

```
def _create_function(name, doc=""):
    """ Create a function for aggregator by name"""

    def _(*args, **kwargs):
        package, new_name = name.split('__')
        if package == 'np':
            cls = NumpyFunc
        elif package == 'scipy':
            cls = ScipyFunc
        elif package == 'ss':
            cls = ScipyStats
        return cls(func=new_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)

    _.__name__ = name
    _.__doc__ = doc
    return _

ALL = [f'np__{func}' for func in np.ma.__all__] + [f'scipy__{func}' for func in ...] + 
 ...

for func_dict in ALL:
    for _name, _doc in func_dict.items():
        globals()[_name] = _create_function(_name, _doc)
del _name, _doc
```

Then you can have something like:

```
x1 = ss__norm_rvs(loc=0, scale=1)
x2 = Operand(x1) + ss__norm_rvs(loc=2, scale=0.5)
x3 = Operand(Operand(x1) * np__exp(x2)) + ss__norm_rvs(loc=-1, scale=2)
```

You could even get rid of the pesky `Operand` by making everything a subclass of `Operand`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your approach is super interesting but I am not sure this really works for the intended purpose. It seems a bit complicated from the user perspective, since they would have to use the construct you have in the "usage" section as opposed to the normal np.function, or scipy.function constructs. I will study your answer in any case.

Comment: Tim, I don't mean to be difficult, but isn't this reinventing a lot of stuff that's already in Sympy? Maybe we should be steering OP in the direction of trying to adapt Sympy for the task.

Comment: @RobertDodier a very valid point! added to the beginning of the answer.

Comment: @RobertDodier however, `sympy` doesn't use `numpy` or `scipy` to evaluate the symbolic expressions, and thus it can't be integrate into OP's workflow out-of-the-box.

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to leverage numpy & scipy by definining functions in Sympy which just forward their arguments to the corresponding numpy/scipy function. The goal would be to postpone evaluation until numerical arguments are available, when numpy/scipy can handle them.

Comment: turns out they do have a hook into `numpy` using `lambdify` function :), but doesn't seems to support `scipy` at the moment.